# Artemis STOMP message expiry

Tags: java, spring, activemq-artemis

From the documentation I still do not understand how to configure the expiration of messages for the [STOMP](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html) protocol in broker.xml.

We have a chat project in which "multicast" addresses are created for each chat

```
topic/chat.1, topic/chat.2, ..., topic/chat.100000
```

Among other things, we use "[Durable Subscriptions](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#durable-subscriptions)".
Thus, even on our unpopular project, the number of topics per month can exceed 50,000, which causes the server to run out of memory, especially if we go to the web console.

I hope that when deleting expired messages, unnecessary addresses and queues will be automatically deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expiry-delay` `address-setting` mentioned in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-expiry.html) to apply an expiration to all incoming messages, e.g.:

```xml
<address-setting match="#">
   <expiry-delay>300000</expiry-delay> <!-- 5 minutes -->
</address-setting>
```

If you're using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.12.0 or later then when the last message expires from an auto-created queue with no consumers then the queue will be auto-deleted by default (and if the corresponding auto-created address then has no queues it will also be auto-deleted by default).

Comment: Many thanks! Another way is the header - expires: (unix time).  

There is another case, the queues for which Durable = true are not deleted (this is logical). However, I could not find information on how to set expires for the queue when the client crashes and does not unsubscribe

Comment: Yes, you can use the `expires` header from the client-side, but that of course requires client changes. The server-side `expiry-delay` doesn't require client changes. *Any* auto-created queue whose message-count and consumer-count is 0 will be auto-deleted by default, even those marked as *durable*. Lastly, the `expiry-delay` applies to *all* messages sent to a matching address so even if a client crashes and does not unsubscribe the messages will eventually expire, although for a durable subscription the queue will remain and continue to receive messages.